# Fonts on external display (4k TV) look awful, sub pixel font smoothing gone haywire?

Tags: font, displayport, thunderbolt-display, display

I have an LG 42UB820V 4K IPS TV - 3840 x 2160 @ 60hz which I connected via an active mini display port to HDMI converter to use with my Mac Mini (HD4000) at 3840 x 2160 @ 30hz.

Everything works fine and dandy, using SwitchResX to make a custom resolution for 30hz.

The problem is I think OS X mistakenly takes the TV as a YCbCr device instead of RGB, or something along those lines. The fonts look awful, with some text having a kind of inverted halo around them!

**Long story short, it actually showed the fonts perfectly at one time and it was beautiful**, but after a restart it seems to have reverted to the 'awful' mode again.

How can I fix it now and forever?

Comment: Does it change when switching color profiles in system prefs?

Comment: No, I mean the color do change a little bit but it's normal.

Comment: If you turn off font smothing (i believe in general oder appearance) does it get better or worse?

Comment: About the same, the sub pixel 'shadow detail' on each letter goes away, but still each character seems jagged as if antialiasing is doing something wrong. For example the letters 'l' and 'L' are nearly always supposed to be displayed perfectly, but here sometimes the upper part of the L is thiner in one word and thicker in another.

Comment: Hmm, does it only happen when it's set to 4k?

Comment: This is the native resolution. Going lower to something like 1920x1080 and everything is twice as big as it should be, and then 'yes' it does seem the problem completely disappears.

Comment: @unmircea, You could possibly try [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/37590/10139).

Comment: @l'L'l Tried it and it just turns on and off the font smoothing.

Comment: @KevinGrabher Managed to zero in on the issue. It seems the LG TV has somekind of processing going on behind the scenes and it just activates even though it's turned off. If I go to the image settings and go into Cinema mode, or any other mode and the back to my custom settings, the effect is gone.

Comment: @KevinGrabher Managed to narrow it down even further. I think I've found the culprit. When you turn the tv on for the first time, this effect takes over. If you cycle through the Image modes Cinema, Game and so on it disappears. This same effect happens if you go Image mode, Expert Control -> Super resolution. Apparently this preprocesses HD input to scale it up to 4K. I'm already giving the TV a 4K signal so I turned it off. It seems that it is on by default, when you turn it on and you have to reapply the Image mode for it to stick. It's a bug! I've checked it multiple times, it's the same.

Comment: @l'L'l Managed to find the culprit read my comment above. It seems even though I turned Super Resolution off the setting resets to on if you turn off the tv and it essentially filters out the fine sub pixel antialias information that OS X puts out and make the fonts appear weird. Temporary fix, reapply the image mode every time you turn on the tv.

Comment: unmircea, I encourage you to either (a) write an answer, to answer your question with the solution, or (b) edit the question to include all of this additional information into the question.  Comments exist only to help you improve your question and can disappear at any time; important information should not be left only in the comments, and people shouldn't have to read the comments to understand your question.  See http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment.

Answer (score 1):

I have/had a similar problem with my MacBook Pro and now my newer MBPr with an Asus 27" monitor. I ended up finding a discussion about it and a script in a forum for Dell Monitors.  The script took the monitors EDID information directly and created a display profile for it that overrode what OS X was trying to automatically configure.

Here is the script on github along with a link to the original topic. https://gist.github.com/ejdyksen/8302862

This worked for me to make my fonts readable again on my Asus VE27q.